# Create list of co-routines and gather them

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm struggling with asyncio in python.
I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
import asyncio

async def create_task(task):
    proc = asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(
        task.code,
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = await proc.communicate()
    if(stdout):
        print (stdout)
    if(stderr):
        print (stderr)

async def main():
    tasks_to_do = *a list of Task objects*
    tasks_to_run = []
    for task in tasks_to_do:
        task_to_run = create_task(task)
        tasks_to_run.append(task_to_run)
        
    L = await asyncio.gather(*tasks_to_run)
    print(L)


asyncio.run(main())
```

So:

1. populate a list of co-routines based on an array of different tasks
2. run all the co-routines and await them.

where each task is a subprocess.

Would this be possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The word “task” seems to be a bit overloaded here. It doesn’t seem like you mean it in the asyncio sense. What specific problem(s) are you having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question almost works as you have written. I've made minor changes to print the time taken at each step. About what you'd expect for 10 pings issued simultaneously

```
import asyncio
import time

start = time.perf_counter()
first = 0

async def create_task(task):
    global start, first
    proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(
        task,
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = await proc.communicate()
    if(stdout):
        #  print (stdout)
        print(first, time.perf_counter() - start)
        first += 1
    if(stderr):
        # print (stderr)
        pass

async def main():
    global start, first
    tasks_to_do = [f"ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w {x}000" for x in range(10)]
    tasks_to_run = []
    for task in tasks_to_do:
        task_to_run = create_task(task)
        tasks_to_run.append(task_to_run)
    L = await asyncio.gather(*tasks_to_run)
    print(time.perf_counter() - start)
    print(L)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Output is ...

```
0 0.04503160000000006
1 0.6204607000000001
2 1.6138199000000002
3 2.6133104
4 3.620059
5 4.617139099999999
6 5.6125441
7 6.617551199999999
8 7.613781399999999
9 8.6230318
8.623507199999999
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```